# should i definitely use "putch" function when i dont use scanf?

Tags: c, windows

i wrote this simple code but it did not give me the true result...should i definitely use "putch" function  when i dont use scanf ?...this is my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    int x, y, area, p, m, d ;
    clrscr();
    printf("enter a number:");
    x = getche();
    printf("\nenter another number:");
    y = getche();
    area = x * y;
    p = (x + y) * 2;
    clrscr();
    printf("area = %d\t p = %d\n", area, p);
    printf("\npress any key to continue:\n");
    m = getche();
    clrscr();
    printf("\nfinish");
    d = getche();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your input, expected output and actual output?

Comment: I don't think using `putch()`, which is not in the standard, is mandatory even if `scanf()` is not used.

Comment: Why do you think you should definitely use `putch()` function when you don't use `scanf()`?

Comment: `x = getche();` This sets `x` to the character code of the first key you press, which is most likely *not* what you want there.

Comment: @MikeCAT this is my input: x=2  y=3 , and output: area:2550  p=202

Comment: @Benjamin What is your *expected* output? Because the output is correct.

Comment: The output is quite natural because ASCII code of `'2'` is 50 and `'3'` is 51. I requested both expected and actual output.

Comment: C has no `<conio.h>` or `getche()` or `clrscr()`. These are Windows API facilities. If you want to learn how to use them, you probably should tag your question `windows` and not `c`. If you want to learn C, don't use these things.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. "*and not `c`*" -  What? It's C code. Why don't tag it C? - "*If you want to learn C, don't use these things.*" - Using implementation-specific libraries is fine. No `language-lawyer` tag in here.

Comment: `getche` reads a character. You need to convert it to an integer if you want to use it as such. And it's not clear what `putch` has to do with any of this.

Comment: `putch` has a completely different purpose than `scanf`. The first is output of characters, while the second is input for a many of things. Why would you think to change one for the other?

Comment: What your goal should be is to delete the ancient DOS header `conio.h` which makes your code 100% non-portable and use the function in `stdio.h` instead. There is room for inclusion if you need to place the keyboard in non-cannonical mode (which is how  the `getch()` function behaves.) This is only due to all OSs having a slightly different method for detailing with terminal input. Outside of that, it should be `stdio.h` only.

Comment: @MikeCAT this is my input: x=2  y=3 , and output: area:2550  p=202 ...i think when i use getch() or getche() i cant use variable in printf.

Comment: `getch()` reads ASCII digits, not integers... A `fgets()` followed by `sscanf()` would be a wise combination.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Tagging it "c" in addition to "windows" is probably OK, but not necessary in my view. It is fine to use implementation-specific libraries. It is not so fine to use them while learning C, unless you want to get confused about what is a part of the language and what is not.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio im just thinking i have learning issues then...what i have to do? comments are confusing ...whats my main problem?

Comment: @Benjamin I can say what you main problem is. You misunderstood something. The program gives the correct output. But we don't know actually what you misunderstood in particular.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio the output is correct because compiler didn't give me any error so i don't know whats the misunderstood too...but when it works, then there is a logical reason for it. whats that? do any conversion or something occur!

Comment: @Benjamin Did you read already the first part of David's answer? I think there is high-probably your misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest hurdle you must clear is understanding all user input in C is *character input*. You are reading ASCII values, see [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/). If there are digits in the ASCII values you read as input, you must convert the digits to numeric values.

In your case you are entering `'2'` (which has ASCII value `50`) and `'3'` (which has ASCII value `51`) and then you perform your calculations using the ASCII values of the characters instead of the numeric values, e.g.

```
    area = x * y;       /* perform calculations */
    p = (x + y) * 2;
```

And you end up with:  `area = 2550      p = 202` because your calculation was done with ASCII values for `'2'` and `'3'` (`50` and `51`) instead of integers `2` and `3`.

There are several ways to handle this. The one recommended is to read the entire line of user input into a buffer (a character array) so the entire line is read (including any stray or extraneous characters) and parse the needed values from the line. You do this with `fgets()` and `sscanf()` validating the return of both. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
...
    fputs ("enter a number (x): ", stdout);     /* prompt */
    /* read user-input and convert string of digits to integer value */
    if (!fgets(buf, MAXC, stdin) || sscanf (buf, "%d", &x) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid x input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    fputs ("enter a number (y): ", stdout);     /* prompt */
    /* read user-input and convert string of digits to integer value */
    if (!fgets(buf, MAXC, stdin) || sscanf (buf, "%d", &y) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid y input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
```

Now you have the integer values for `x` and `y` and can complete your calculations. If you happened to slip and type `"2w"` instead of `'2'`, no harm done, the extraneous characters in the buffer are silently discarded. And if they were in an invalid order, e.g. `"w2"`, a *matching failure* would occur in `sscanf()` the check of the return would fail, and your program would adequately handle the error by providing an error message and exiting with an error code (`EXIT_FAILURE` - `1`) returned to the shell.

A full example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {
    
    char buf[MAXC];     /* buffer to hold each line of input */
    int x, y, area, p;  /* your lenght, width, area, perimeter */
    
    fputs ("enter a number (x): ", stdout);     /* prompt */
    /* read user-input and convert string of digits to integer value */
    if (!fgets(buf, MAXC, stdin) || sscanf (buf, "%d", &x) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid x input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    fputs ("enter a number (y): ", stdout);     /* prompt */
    /* read user-input and convert string of digits to integer value */
    if (!fgets(buf, MAXC, stdin) || sscanf (buf, "%d", &y) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid y input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    area = x * y;       /* perform calculations */
    p = (x + y) * 2;
    
    printf ("\narea = %d\t p = %d\n", area, p); /* output result */

#if defined (_WIN32) || defined (_WIN64)
    getchar();  /* hold windows terminal open only on windows */
#endif
}
```

(**note:** the final preprocessor conditional simply checks if this is compiled on windows, and if so, includes the final `getchar()` so the terminal window is held open until a character is typed along with return)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/area_perimeter
enter a number (x): 2
enter a number (y): 3

area = 6        p = 10
```

What about extraneous input or accidental input?

```
$ ./bin/area_perimeter
enter a number (x): 2 is the value for x for my project
enter a number (y): 3 is the value for y

area = 6        p = 10
```

The error resulting from using ASCII values:

```
$ ./bin/area_perimeter
enter a number (x): 50
enter a number (y): 51

area = 2550      p = 202
```

Since `conio.h` wasn't used and only C-standard functions -- your code is 100% portable. Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: That's an elaborate answer! I would change "*and then you perform your calculations using the ASCII values instead of the numeric value*" to "*and then you perform your calculations using the ASCII values instead of the numeric value of the characters*" for the sake of understanding.

Comment: Good point. Will do that. If you find others like that, feel free to make the edit. I have no problem with that.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i almost understand why the output is correct...i have to work on that more...also my question is completely wrong!! thanks for your guidance...

Comment: @Benjamin - we all started out programming at the same level and we've all made the same mistakes -- key is to learn from them `:)`

Answer (score 0):

> should i definitely use “putch” function when i dont use scanf?

No, you might instead stick to standard C functions. Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

You should however read the documentation of your C compiler (perhaps some [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...)

Be also aware that in 2020 [UTF-8 is practically used everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/). So you might be interested by [libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/).